# When we search for a product through the search bar, it is not showing any search results

Tags: product, magento2.4, search, elasticsearch, meta-title

When we search for a product through the search bar, it is not showing any search results.

Upon checking for the issue we have seen the following error :

```
 "caused_by":{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Cannot search on field [meta_title] since it is not indexed."}}}]}
```

The error is displayed in **/var/log/exception.log**

It seems that the error is with elastic search. Can anybody provide some solutions???

Comment: Have you tried reindexing?

Comment: If reindexing didn't produce any errors in the catalog product search, then check for the elasticsearch config which will be in /etc/apache2/sites-available.

Comment: @Jason we re-indexing and check elasticsearch is active